# Deleting only the content of the two sub folders

Tags: c#

I have my codes here that will delete but It will delete including the two subfolders. I want to delete only the content of the two sub folders.

```
          Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(txtfilename.Text), File.Delete);
          System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(txtfilename.Text);

            foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Delete();
            }
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                dir.Delete(true);
            }
```

If someone can debug or show some solutions, Thank you so much.

Comment: what is `dir.Delete(true);` for..?

Comment: Yes, It will delete inside the directories. For example this is my directory        e:\user\sam\des   I need to map only des folder but the des folder had a two sub folders and I want to delete only the content of the two sub folders.

Comment: Then stop deleting all the directories, and don't delete the ones you want to keep. You have the name of each one in `dir`, but you're just deleting everything in sight in your loop. It helps if you actually read the code.

Comment: Yeah. That code is not suitable for it. I need some guide how to delete only the content of the two sub folders. Because in my form in the text field we can select only one folder directory.

Comment: hi @Sam, an `if` would help you. like checking whether the directory name is not to be deleted.. well, just think of something to discern *yes, delete this folder* and *no, don't remove this*.

Comment: My goodness that is out of my brain directory. Can you show me some code to picture out how would it be. hashtag for beginner in programming.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I solved my own problem. I used this code. After searching some codes and combine each Idea and that's the reason I come up this kind of code but I don't totally understand what I'm doing.

```
   string local = txtfilename.Text;
   string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(local,
                   "*.csv*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

   List<string> singleDirNames = dirs.Select(x => new 
   FileInfo(x).Directory.Name).Distinct().ToList();

   foreach (string filePath in dirs)
      {
      if (filePath.Contains(".csv"))
      File.Delete(filePath);
      }
```

Because the content of the two sub folders are csv file. I specifically target the file extension to delete. I less my want into a certain extension to be delete. I really want to delete everything inside the two sub folders. Can Anyone improve my anwswer?